# how can convert jquery code to functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multi html block with same code like this:

```
<div id="up1">
   <input id="sub1" />
</div>


<div id="up2">
   <input id="sub2" />
</div>

.
.
.

<div id="upn">
   <input id="subn" />
</div>
```

for each html these block I have same jquery code (with own id for each of them)

like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#up1",function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... some code ...
})); 

$(document).on("change", "#up2",function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... some code ...
})); 
.
.
.

$(document).on("change", "#upn",function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... some code ...
}));
```

this is my qestion

how to avoid repeating code?..

maybe u suggest me I must use class instead id,But it's not my answer.I want use only id.

I must use id,not class... because I want print result (or send data) on it's block.

seems I must use a function, but how can I call them in a function?

for example is this valid?

```
function myfunction(id1,id2) {
$(document).on("change", "#up1",function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... some code ...
})); 

}


myfunction('up1','sub1');
myfunction('up2','sub2');
myfunction('up3','sub3');
```

Comment: *"because I want print result (or send data) on it's block"* ... doesn't mean you need to use `id`. Common misconception  issue when learning but there are numerous ways to traverse within instances of a class

Comment: You **can** and you **should** use various IDs, but **same** class on those elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use multiple selectors:

```
$(document).on("change", "#up1, #up2, #upn", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... some code ...
}));
```

In this case if any of elements `up1` ... `upn` is changed the event handler will be fired. Additionally you need to access the item that was changed by using `$(this)` instead of accessing it directly by ID.

To access the `sub` element you can use some other selector based on your parent element, for example:

```
$(document).on("change", "#up1, #up2, #upn", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sub = $(this).find('input').eq(0);  // find first input element inside changed element
}));
```

Or if it possible change your HTML structure not to use ID for `sub` items and use class instead:

```
<div id="up1">
   <input id="sub1" class="sub" />
</div>
```

In this case you can use class selector:

```
$(document).on("change", "#up1, #up2, #upn", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    // find first element inside changed element that has class 'sub':
    var sub = $(this).find('.sub').eq(0);      
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a class to target multiple items:

JS

```
$(document).on("change", ".sub", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    ... some code ...
}));
```

HTML

```
<div id="up1" class="sub">
   <input id="sub1" />
</div>


<div id="up2" class="sub">
   <input id="sub2"  />
</div>

.
.
.

<div id="upn" class="sub">
   <input id="subn"  />
</div>
```

You can also do something like this:

```
function myFunction(id1,id2){
   ... code ...
}

$(document).on('change', '.sub', function(e){
    var thisID = $(this).prop('id'),
        inputID = $(this).find('input').prop('id');

    e.preventDefault();

    myFunction(thisID, inputID);
});
```

Also, just making sure you want your change event on the div and not the input?

Answer (score 1):

Use css attribute selector to target all divs whose `id` starts with `up`:

```
$(document).on("change", "div[id^='up']", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Something changed! ID of div: "+ $(this).attr("id") ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write ids to access the elements. Class can suffice too and can make your code look very small. If HTML is like:

```
<div class='input-container'>
    <input type=text />
</div>
<div class='input-container'>
    <input type=text />
</div>
<div class='input-container'>
    <input type=text />
</div>
```

Then jQuery can be written as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.input-container input[type="text"]', function(){
        //your code
    });
});
```